# Is there an inverse function for poly?

Tags: r, poly

We can generate orthogonal polynomials in R with
`pp <- poly(cars$speed, 2)`
Is there a way to get the original values out of the result `pp` (inverse poly function)?

In other words, what should the function `f` look like that returns the following result:

`f(poly(cars$speed, 2)) == cars$speed`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cars$speed` must be of the form a + b * pp[, 1] for some scalars a and b and knowing that the `coefs` attribute of poly objects contains values which can be used for reconstruction we find the following reconstruction of `cars$speed` as `speed`.

```
pp <- poly(cars$speed, 2)
speed <- with(attr(pp, "coefs"), alpha[1] + sqrt(norm2)[3] * pp[, 1])

all.equal(speed, cars$speed)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Awsome, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!